# How to calculate index from row and column?

Tags: language-agnostic

I want to calculate an index (base 0) for any given row and column where rows and columns are base 1 and the number of columns is known, e.g. 2

If max_columns is 2 and index is 5, then to calculate row number from an index:

```
Row = (index % max_columns) + (int)(index / max_columns)
    = (5 % 2) + (int)(5 / 2)
    = 1 + 2
    = 3
```

To calculate column number from index

```
Col = max_columns - (index % max_columns)
    = 2 - (5 % 2)
    = 2 - 1
    = 1
```

Question is how to calculate row and column from any index where the index is base 0.  This is to calculate an index into an array in a java application.

The correct solution for me as supplied by 'Willem Van Onsem':

Where `Row` is 3, `Col` is 2 and `max_columns` is 2:

```
Index = (Row * max_columns) + Col - max_columns - 1
      = (3 * 2) + 2 - 2 - 1
      = 6 + (-1)
      = 5
```

Comment: The above formulas to calculate the `Row` and `Col` calculate - afaik - not the correct row and column.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Given every row consists out of *n* columns, the zero-based index for the column and row are:

```
int row = index/n;
int col = index%n;
```

Now since your `row` and `col` are offset `1`, you simply add `1` to both:

```
int row1 = (index/n)+1;
int col1 = (index%n)+1;
```

---

For the **inverse function**, if `row` and `col` are offset `0`, you can calculate the index as:

```
int index = row*n+col;
```

or if the indexes are offset `1`:

```
int index = row1*n+col1-n-1;
```

Comment: can you add ( and ) to the index/n+1 ?

Answer (score 0):

```
row = (int) (index / max_columns + 1)
col = (index % max_columns + 1)
```