# Calculate index for number combinations

Tags: algorithm, math, indexing

I have a vector that includes a value for every possible combination of two numbers out of a bigger group of *n* numbers (from 0 to (*n*-1)), excluding combinations where both numbers are the same.
For instance, if *n* = 4, combinations will be the ones shown in columns *number1* and *number2*.

```
    number1  number2 vector-index value
    0        1       0             3
    0        2       1             98
    0        3       2             0
    1        0       3             44
    1        2       4             6
    1        3       5             3
    2        0       6             2
    2        1       7             43
    2        3       8             23
    3        0       9             11
    3        1       10            54
    3        2       11            7
```

There are always `n*(n-1)` combinations and therefore that is the number of elements in the vector (12 elements in the example above).

## Problem

In order to access the values in the vector I need a expression that allows me to figure out the corresponding index number for every combination.
If combinations where *number1=number2* were included, the index number could be figured our using:

```
    index = number1*(n-1)+number2
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35748843/calculate-index-from-row-and-column) is related but includes also combinations where *number1=number2*.

Is there any expression to calculate the index in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, notice that all the pairs can be grouped into blocks of size (n-1), where n is the number of different indices. This means that given a pair (i, j), the index of the block containing it will be i(n-1). Within that block the indices are laid out sequentially, skipping over index i. If j < i, then we just look j steps past the start of the block. Otherwise, we look j-1 steps past it. Overall this gives the formula

```
int index = i * (n - 1) + (j < i? j : j - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the only difference is when `number2` is greater than `number1`, when this happens a value from `number2` sequence was skipped, so you will need to decrease the count, something like this:

```
index = number1 * (n - 1) + number2 - (number2 > number1 ? 1 : 0)
```